# Initialize a variable in a test (MockMVC)

Tags: java, spring, mocking

I'm trying to run 2 tests with MockMVC (Spring framework).

- The first one add a user. When the user is added, an `userID` is generated, and returned.
- The second should delete the added user from this `userID`.

At the start of my test class, I have this variable: `String userID;`

Here is the test where I create the user (it works). After creating the user, I get from the response the generated ID for this user.

```
@Test
public void it_adds_a_new_user() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mockMvc
        .perform(post("/users")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content("User infos, in JSON..."))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();
    //Next lines just take the ID from the response
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    matcher.find();

    this.userID = matcher.group();       
    System.out.println(userID); //Correctly print the generated ID
}
```

Now, I try to delete this poor guy:

```
@Test
public void it_deletes_the_new_user() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(userID); //It prints null!
    mockMvc.perform(delete("/users/" + userID)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .andExpect(status().isOk()); //400 because userID is null :-(
}
```

The problem is that `userID` is correctly initialized in the first test, but is `null` in the second (it is a class variable). I don't understand why.

Can you help me running those tests, and if possible explain me why `userID == null` on my second test ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create `getter` and `setter` method for set and get the value userID like:
`void setUserId(matcher.group())`---->should be `inside it_adds_a_new_user()`
now you have setted the userId

add one gette method also,
get the value by calling `getUserId()`----->should be inside `it_deletes_the_new_user()`

since i dont know the structuer of your program so giving you just an idea to solve you problem.